# Java Generics - any run time benefits

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to know if there are any run time advantages to Generics provided from Java5. I mean, I know that we can achieve type safety for classes/collections and allow a range of possible objects for a generic, but are there any benefits that we get at Run time ahead of compilation time?

Comment: what does it mean to "get at Run time ahead of compilation time"? How would you run without compiling first?

Comment: Well, the runtime benefit is fewer ClassCastExceptions

Comment: Fewer ClassCast exceptions id not really a runtime benefit - you aren't getting them anyway if your code is correct. The benefit is that it's easier to write correct code.

Answer (score 10):

Java generics are removed at runtime via [erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so the performance should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about them is available through reflection (say in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getTypeParameters%28%29 ) but they don't make your programs run better.

CoolBeans, I took him to mean "beyond" compilation time benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but it's very minor.

When you use generics, you don't need to use `instanceof` and casting everywhere, so the bytecode instructions that do type checking for those instructions are no generated. On the downside, you can wind up with some fairly low-level errors at runtime if you link to old versions of your classes without recompiling them.

Still, if you heavily use a tight loop that otherwise needs a cast, then I suppose generics might speed things up a tiny, tiny bit. But performance improvement is not the point of using them.

Comment: Most casting instructions are still generated by the compiler, and when you wrote your program without generics really the same, you would not need your instanceof tests, too.